# Error passing globals to Jinja2Templates constructor with FastAPI

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, fastapi

According to the [starlette sources](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/62b5b6042a39289ed561580c251c233250c3c088/starlette/templating.py#L71ls), it seems the correct way to set up globals is simply to pass them to the constructor of `fastapi.templating.Jinja2Templates` as you [would do](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Template.globals) with `jinja2.Environment`.

So I have the following code trying to prepare for using jinja2 templates in FastAPI, with a dummy global "myglobal" for testing:

```
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

templates = None
try:
    templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=f"{webroot}", globals={"myglobal":"somevalue"})
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception("No templates folder found, skipping...")
```

On application startup, the exception triggers with the following output:

```
No templates folder found, skipping...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/main.py", line 22, in <module>
     templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=f"{webroot}", globals={"myglobal":"somevalue"})
   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/templating.py", line 74, in __init__
     self.env = self._create_env(directory, **env_options)
   File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/templating.py", line 89, in _create_env
     env = jinja2.Environment(**env_options)
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'globals'
```

So my question is, *what am I doing wrong here*? *How can I pass globals to my templates in FastAPI*?

Answer (score 0):

```
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from jinja2 import Environment

class MyTemplates(Jinja2Templates):
    def __init__(self, directory: str, globals: dict = None, **options):
        if globals is None:
            globals = {}
        jinja_env = Environment(**options)
        jinja_env.globals.update(globals)
        super().__init__(directory=directory, jinja_env=jinja_env)
```

You can then instantiate MyTemplates instead of Jinja2Templates and pass in your globals as a dictionary using this

templates = MyTemplates(directory=f"{webroot}", globals={"myglobal": "somevalue"})

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. Environment.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jinja_env'